# Possible to add SQL server express to Azure "websites"

Tags: azure

I understand that I can add SQL server express to an Azure virtual machine but can I add the DB to azure "websites", or do I need to use Azure SQL if I want to use a SQL DB for Azure "websites"?

Comment: Possible duplicate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293002/is-it-possible-to-run-sql-express-within-a-azure-web-role

Comment: My understanding is that there is a difference between "roles" and "websites". Should i assume if its not possible on "role" its not possible on "websites" either? THX

Comment: @Vinod, this is not buplicate. The referenced question is about Cloud Services (Web/Worker roles) and the current question is about Azure WebSites (a different service/platform).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No,

You can't use/add/install any software when using Azure WebSites. The data storage possibilities for your application running in Azure WebSites are: Azure SQL Database (former SQL Azure), Azure Blob Storage, Azure Table Storage, MySQL database (currently only provided as part of provisioning PHP CMS's in Azure WebSites).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you have to create a SQL Compact Edition in your root, not SQL Server Express.

I've written an [article](http://sincode.blogspot.tw/2014/09/sql-compact-edition-database-azure.html) about it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169526/use-azure-websites-with-sql-compact-edition-for-free) is my related question post on StackOverflow, and [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=883) is the English version I found.

### Below is the solution after my research:

Step by Step like this:

1. **Install two Nuget packages** (`EntityFrame.SqlServerCompact` & `Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition`)
2. **Put your SQL database file(.sdf/.mdf) in APP_Data folder**
   (Add the connection string like this in order to use it:

   ```
   <add name ="DefaultConnection" connectionString ="Data Source=|DataDirectory|CompactDB.sdf" providerName ="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />)
   ```
3. Publish full project include above SQL database file to AzureWebsites.

You'll find it can work well, and is totally free.

Answer (score 0):

It is preinstalled. If you go to KUDU/Environment you will find

```
Connection Strings
  LocalSqlServer
    ConnectionString = data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
    ProviderName = System.Data.SqlClient
```

Comment: The main question is how to connect to it from outside?